# SQL Reporting services external NAT

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a Reporting services URL accessible internally on a Server.  I want to expose this to a user who is not on the same network -  but can access the network via a firewall....     the RS instance is thus setup with SSL etc.

The server is already running one SSL site -  so we have used a different port number..  eg. 446 for the RS site.

So internally the URL is as :

http://server:446/Reports_Test   and this works as expected.

Externally we NAT 443 on a specific name to 446 intenally

So externally  I ask for (via https)

reporting.example.com/Reports_Test

I get the login prompt as expected...  but then once successful... the site redirects to (via HTTPS)

reporting.example.com:446/Reports_Test

Is there a way to stop the RS changing the port number ?

---

Answer (score 0):

Use the Reporting Services Configuration tool to configure the URLs.

To set advanced properties on a URL:

- On either the Web Service URL or Web Portal URL page, click Advanced.
- Click Add.
- Click IP Address or Host Header Name. If you specify a host header, be sure to specify a name that the DNS service can resolve. If you are specifying publicly available domain name, include the whole URL, including http://www.
- Specify the port. If you specify a custom port, the URL to the application must always include the port number.
- Click OK.
  Test the URL by opening a browser window and entering the URL.

From:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630447.aspx

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion... but the URL Fails to reserve because of another SSL binding for 443 with a different cert...  despite that the URL still shows under the URLs...  but I now cant edit or remove it.